# Identify the BSSID of the AP that user is currently connected to

Tags: mobile, wifi, httprequest, access-point, bssid

Working on a project for class specific to the college network.

The idea is that if we can fetch an identifying characteristic of the web session/connection on campus, we can map out and associate the AP with their location coordinates and plot them on a map. More specifically, we're trying to determine which AP the device is connected to.

Basically the user would bring up a webpage on the intranet from a wi-fi enabled device (preferably an iPad or iPod Touch), and either on the page load or through an action event an unique identifier is captured; which we could in turn associate with lat & long coordinates. The idea here is that the unique identifier would be sent and stored into to a DB field (almost like a guestbook submission). Then, externally on a separate public webpage - viewers would be able to see these unique identifiers returned and translated as the most recently visited locations plotted on a map. This would translate to a manual "check-in" tracking service.

Capturing the IP address will not work as they are not static.

Comment: Sorry, didn't clarify the question... Is there a way to Identify the BSSID (or some other unique identifier) of the AP that user is currently connected to through any type of web script?

Answer (score 0):

BSSID is part of the active connection attributes set and as such is stored inside the client networking component of the OS. You need to query it by calling the appropriate API of your OS (e.g., in Windows it would be `WlanQueryInterface`). You'll also need to be able to call this API from script, you can find some info about this here: [How to call Windows API functions in JScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503562/how-to-call-windows-api-functions-in-jscript)